# Java : Compare, mark and interpret HTML texts in Java

Tags: java, html, string, string-comparison

I am working on a Java project, where there is an HTML editor and the user can enter text in a html-editor(ckeditor) and the actual HTML text is saved in the database.

Now when a user comes again next time, and edits the same text, I would like to show the difference between the two by comparing it from the database.

The most important problem I am facing is, even if any  comparator-tool knows that style from Italic has changed to Bold, the output of the comparator is it `strike-throughs` the word `Italic` and shows `Bold` was inserted in place of that.

But that doesn't explain the **Intention** or **Action** of the actual edit. The intention/action was that the user made it from Italic to Bold. What I am looking for is a tool, which instead of showing that the word Italic was removed and Bold was added in place of that, would show me the `Italic` word/sentence first which is strikethrough and the replacement by the `Bold`  word/sentence.

I hope what I mean is clear. I have been trying to achieve this for quite some time. I tried diff_match_patch, daisydiff, etc, nothing helped.

My trials :

```
/*

            String oldTextHtml = mnotes1.getMnotetext();
            String newTextHTML = mnotes.getMnotetext();


            oldTextHtml = oldTextHtml.replace("<br>","\n");
            oldTextHtml = Jsoup.clean(oldTextHtml, Whitelist.basic());
           oldTextHtml = Jsoup.parse(oldTextHtml).text();

            newTextHTML = newTextHTML.replace("<br>","\n");
            newTextHTML = Jsoup.clean(newTextHTML,Whitelist.basic());
            newTextHTML = Jsoup.parse(newTextHTML).text();


            diff_match_patch diffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch();
            LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> deltas = diffMatchPatch.diff_main(oldTextHtml, newTextHTML);
            diffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(deltas);
            newText += diffMatchPatch.diff_prettyHtml(deltas);
            groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
            groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newText);
            noEdit = true;
*/


           List<String> oldTextList = Arrays.asList(mnotes1.getMnotetext().split("(\\.|\\n)"));
            List<String> newTextList = Arrays.asList(mnotes.getMnotetext().split("(\\.|\\n)"));
            if (oldTextList.size() == newTextList.size()) {

                for (int current = 0; current < oldTextList.size(); current++) {
                    if (isLineDifferent(oldTextList.get(current), newTextList.get(current))) {
                        noEdit = true;
                        diff_match_patch diffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch();
                        LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> deltas = diffMatchPatch.diff_main(oldTextList.get(current), newTextList.get(current));
                        diffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(deltas);
                        newText += diffMatchPatch.diff_prettyHtml(deltas);
                        groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
                        groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newText);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!(mnotes.getMnotetext().equals(mnotes1.getMnotetext()))) {
                    if (isLineDifferent(mnotes1.getMnotetext(), mnotes.getMnotetext())) {
                        diff_match_patch diffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch();

                        LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> deltas = diffMatchPatch.diff_main(mnotes1.getMnotetext(),
                                mnotes.getMnotetext());
                        diffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(deltas);
                        newText += diffMatchPatch.diff_prettyHtml(deltas);
                        groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
                        noEdit = true;
                    }
                    groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newText);
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
                }
            }
```

If anyone has any idea how I can achieve this, kindly let me know. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Edit*

I was asked for an image. Explanation and then the image.

```
Old text : <style= bold>Hello</style>
new Text : <style = Italic>Hello</style>
```

Difference output expected :

[image: As in this image.]

Comment: Why was this question voted to close, I wouldn't mind knowing that because it's been around 2-3 weeks we are trying to search for an efficient and correct solution, but we have nothing... What does the user who voted to close has that made him/her think this question is irrelevant or not a proper question in any manner?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I assume one could argue to close this because you literally say: *What I am looking for is a tool,*, and asking for tools in the literal sense is not allowed on SO.

Comment: Maybe: https://github.com/ibakayoko/ckeditor_track_changes (As a side note: if you click on close, you can see the reason)

Comment: @BramVanroy : It might be, but someone might have also worked on a similar problem before and they have some code which I can use to solve this problem. I don't understand this purist/robotic approach that if the user is asking for a tool, then it should be closed..Also my last sentence indicates that 'Any help would be nice', and also I have referred what I have tried and failed. I would just think this is not taking into consideration the larger picture in this question. I hope I didn't offend you, but the actions of user dictates we have neither tried and looking for a free meal!!!

Comment: "I hope what I mean is clear" - Not sufficiently, no.  You say you have tools which will "`strike-through` the word `Italic` and shows `Bold` was inserted in place of that", and say you want to "show me the `Italic` word/sentence first which is strikethrough and the replacement by the `Bold` word/sentence".  I don't see how those are really any different from each other.  Perhaps you could include some examples of desired outputs for sample inputs?

Comment: @aroth : I will create some images and post it as soon as they are done.

Comment: Also, sounds like maybe what you want is not a "word/sentence" diff but a "DOM node" diff.  As in, you want a tool (or algorithm) that can compare one tree with another and highlight what the differences are, apparently in a context-aware way.  So perhaps try something like [this tool here](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom).  Or search for other tools that claim to support [DOM diffing](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=dom+diff).

Comment: @aroth : Something in Java is preferred.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. Your problem is almost infinitely complex. Core questions: What should your program be able to understand? (HTML versions? CSS, too?) What should be diff’ed as equal, what as different? An anpproach could be: First, transform your HTML to a list of characters along with their properties. Then diff. Then transform your diff result to what you want to display to the user.

Comment: @Paramaeleon : Thank you!! No, Only HTML I am expecting, no CSS, CKeditor is stripped and only essential parts like color, list, bold, italic, etc are taken. I have also uploaded an image for what is required. Kindly check it out.

Comment: @aroth : Image uploaded... Kindly check it out. :-)

Comment: Why not use the track changes plugin for CKEditor?  That's what it was created for.

Comment: @QuestionMarks : We are checking it out as we speak.. Kindly give us to time to check. Also, if there is anything in Java, that would be awesome.

Comment: If you're already using CKEditor, it's a no-brainer.  It's a great plugin and allows for multiple users to make and track changes (it will show highlights in different colors for different users, and/or show the username on hover over the change).

Comment: @QuestionMarks : We are looking into Java options as we already have a lot of JS which is creating performance problems for us. Kindly consider that situation as well. Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg - you are already using JS for CKEditor.  Are you saying you want to replace CKEditor entirely?  You might want to mention that in your post.  Otherwise I'm not sure why you would be opposed to adding a plug-in to it that accomplishes exactly what you need.

Comment: Did you ever think about going to the [CKEditor Developer Center](https://dev.ckeditor.com/) and create an issue for that? Perhaps there is more interest to implement this among the community.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I did a Probe of concept about an open source library that implements the diff command on java, and many other features.

Basically I compared two java files and get the modified lines between them, with that information I think it would be easy to achieve what you want.

Basically I have two java files under `src/test/resources/files` folder

File1

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff;

import difflib.Chunk;
import difflib.Delta;
import difflib.DiffUtils;
import difflib.Patch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileComparator {

    private final File original;

    private final File revised;

    public FileComparator(File original, File revised) {
        this.original = original;
        this.revised = revised;
    }

    public List<Chunk> getChangesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.CHANGE);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getInsertsFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.INSERT);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getDeletesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.DELETE);
    }

    private List<Chunk> getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE type) throws IOException {
        final List<Chunk> listOfChanges = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        final List<Delta> deltas = getDeltas();
        for (Delta delta : deltas) {
            if (delta.getType() == type) {
                listOfChanges.add(delta.getRevised());
            }
        }
        return listOfChanges;
    }

    private List<Delta> getDeltas() throws IOException {

        final List<String> originalFileLines = fileToLines(original);
        final List<String> revisedFileLines = fileToLines(revised);

        final Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalFileLines, revisedFileLines);

        return patch.getDeltas();
    }

    private List<String> fileToLines(File file) throws IOException {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    <style= bold>Hello</style>

}
```

File2

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff;

import difflib.Chunk;
import difflib.Delta;
import difflib.DiffUtils;
import difflib.Patch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileComparator {

    private final File original;

    private final File revised;

    public FileComparator(File original, File revised) {
        this.original = original;
        this.revised = revised;
    }

    public List<Chunk> getChangesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.CHANGE);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getInsertsFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.INSERT);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getDeletesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.DELETE);
    }

    private List<Chunk> getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE type) throws IOException {
        final List<Chunk> listOfChanges = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        final List<Delta> deltas = getDeltas();
        for (Delta delta : deltas) {
            if (delta.getType() == type) {
                listOfChanges.add(delta.getRevised());
            }
        }
        return listOfChanges;
    }

    private List<Delta> getDeltas(String nuevoParam) throws IOException {

        final List<String> originalFileLines = fileToLines(original);
        final List<String> revisedFileLines = fileToLines(revised);

        final Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalFileLines, revisedFileLines);

        return patch.getDeltas();
    }

    private List<String> fileToLines(File file, String nuevoParam) throws IOException {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    <style = Italic>Hello</style>

    private void nuevoMetodoCool(File file) {

    }

}
```

A brief FileComparator class (remember it was a POC :D)

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff;

import difflib.Chunk;
import difflib.Delta;
import difflib.DiffUtils;
import difflib.Patch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileComparator {

    private final File original;

    private final File revised;

    public FileComparator(File original, File revised) {
        this.original = original;
        this.revised = revised;
    }

    public List<Chunk> getChangesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.CHANGE);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getInsertsFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.INSERT);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getDeletesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.DELETE);
    }

    private List<Chunk> getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE type) throws IOException {
        final List<Chunk> listOfChanges = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        final List<Delta> deltas = getDeltas();
        for (Delta delta : deltas) {
            if (delta.getType() == type) {
                listOfChanges.add(delta.getRevised());
            }
        }
        return listOfChanges;
    }

    private List<Delta> getDeltas() throws IOException {

        final List<String> originalFileLines = fileToLines(original);
        final List<String> revisedFileLines = fileToLines(revised);

        final Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalFileLines, revisedFileLines);

        return patch.getDeltas();
    }

    private List<String> fileToLines(File file) throws IOException {
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        return lines;
    }

}
```

And a Junit for it

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.everis.car.javadiff.FileComparator;

import difflib.Chunk;

public class FileComparatorTest {

    private final File original = new File("./src/test/resources/files/FileComparatorv1.java");

    private final File revised = new File("./src/test/resources/files/FileComparatorv2.java");

    @Test
    public void shouldGetChangesBetweenFiles() {

        final FileComparator comparator = new FileComparator(original, revised);

        try {
            final List<Chunk> changesFromOriginal = comparator.getChangesFromOriginal();

            final int changeNum = changesFromOriginal.size();
            System.out.println("Tamaño de cambios: " + changeNum);

            for (int i = 0; i < changeNum; i++) {

                final Chunk change = changesFromOriginal.get(i);
                final int firstLineOfFirstChange = change.getPosition() + 1;
                final int changeSize = change.size();
                //final String changeText = change.getLines().get(0).toString();

                System.out.println("Cambio nº " + i);
                System.out.println("firstLineOfFirstChange: " + firstLineOfFirstChange);
                System.out.println("changeSize: " + changeSize);
                System.out.println("change text: ");
                showTest(change.getLines());

            }

            /*assertEquals(3, changesFromOriginal.size());

            final Chunk firstChange = changesFromOriginal.get(0);
            final int firstLineOfFirstChange = firstChange.getPosition() + 1;
            final int firstChangeSize = firstChange.size();
            assertEquals(2, firstLineOfFirstChange);
            assertEquals(1, firstChangeSize);
            final String firstChangeText = firstChange.getLines().get(0).toString();
            assertEquals("Line 3 with changes", firstChangeText);

            final Chunk secondChange = changesFromOriginal.get(1);
            final int firstLineOfSecondChange = secondChange.getPosition() + 1;
            final int secondChangeSize = secondChange.size();
            assertEquals(4, firstLineOfSecondChange);
            assertEquals(2, secondChangeSize);
            final String secondChangeFirstLineText = secondChange.getLines().get(0).toString();
            final String secondChangeSecondLineText = secondChange.getLines().get(1).toString();
            assertEquals("Line 5 with changes and", secondChangeFirstLineText);
            assertEquals("a new line", secondChangeSecondLineText);

            final Chunk thirdChange = changesFromOriginal.get(2);
            final int firstLineOfThirdChange = thirdChange.getPosition() + 1;
            final int thirdChangeSize = thirdChange.size();
            assertEquals(11, firstLineOfThirdChange);
            assertEquals(1, thirdChangeSize);
            final String thirdChangeText = thirdChange.getLines().get(0).toString();
            assertEquals("Line 10 with changes", thirdChangeText);*/

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            fail("Error running test shouldGetChangesBetweenFiles " + ioe.toString());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetInsertsBetweenFiles() {

        final FileComparator comparator = new FileComparator(original, revised);

        try {
            final List<Chunk> insertsFromOriginal = comparator.getInsertsFromOriginal();

            final int changeNum = insertsFromOriginal.size();
            System.out.println("Tamaño de inserciones: " + changeNum);

            for (int i = 0; i < changeNum; i++) {

                final Chunk change = insertsFromOriginal.get(i);
                final int firstLineOfFirstChange = change.getPosition() + 1;
                final int changeSize = change.size();
                //final String changeText = change.getLines().get(0).toString();

                System.out.println("insercion nº " + i);
                System.out.println("firstLineOfFirstInsertion: " + firstLineOfFirstChange);
                System.out.println("insertion Size: " + changeSize);
                System.out.println("insertion text: ");
                showTest(change.getLines());

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            fail("Error running test shouldGetInsertsBetweenFiles " + ioe.toString());
        }
        /*try {
            final List<Chunk> insertsFromOriginal = comparator.getInsertsFromOriginal();
            assertEquals(1, insertsFromOriginal.size());

            final Chunk firstInsert = insertsFromOriginal.get(0);
            final int firstLineOfFirstInsert = firstInsert.getPosition() + 1;
            final int firstInsertSize = firstInsert.size();
            assertEquals(7, firstLineOfFirstInsert);
            assertEquals(1, firstInsertSize);
            final String firstInsertText = firstInsert.getLines().get(0).toString();
            assertEquals("new line 6.1", firstInsertText);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            fail("Error running test shouldGetInsertsBetweenFiles " + ioe.toString());
        }*/
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetDeletesBetweenFiles() {

        final FileComparator comparator = new FileComparator(original, revised);

        try {
            final List<Chunk> deletesFromOriginal = comparator.getDeletesFromOriginal();

            final int changeNum = deletesFromOriginal.size();
            System.out.println("Tamaño de deletes: " + changeNum);

            for (int i = 0; i < changeNum; i++) {

                final Chunk change = deletesFromOriginal.get(i);
                final int firstLineOfFirstChange = change.getPosition() + 1;
                final int changeSize = change.size();
                //final String changeText = change.getLines().get(0).toString();

                System.out.println("delete nº " + i);
                System.out.println("firstLineOfFirstDelete: " + firstLineOfFirstChange);
                System.out.println("delete Size: " + changeSize);
                System.out.println("delete text: ");
                showTest(change.getLines());

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            fail("Error running test shouldGetInsertsBetweenFiles " + ioe.toString());
        }

        /*try {
            final List<Chunk> deletesFromOriginal = comparator.getDeletesFromOriginal();
            assertEquals(1, deletesFromOriginal.size());

            final Chunk firstDelete = deletesFromOriginal.get(0);
            final int firstLineOfFirstDelete = firstDelete.getPosition() + 1;
            assertEquals(1, firstLineOfFirstDelete);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            fail("Error running test shouldGetDeletesBetweenFiles " + ioe.toString());
        }*/
    }

    private void showTest(List<?> texts) {

        if (texts != null) {
            for (Object s : texts) {
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.onuba.car</groupId>
    <artifactId>javadiffpoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JavaDiff ::  POC</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GUAVA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.java-diff-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>diffutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Sorry about some logs and some little stuffs in Spanish :D, maybe with that you can achieve what you want.

The lib home page: https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/ There is a tutorial link at the end of the page (in Spanish)

Hope helps!

**UPDATE**

I did a simple class that generate a file with the differences as strike out lines with this code (I don´t understand quite well your desired format, you can add more decorators if you need)

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import difflib.Chunk;

public class Comparer {

    private final File original = new File("./src/test/resources/files/FileComparatorv1.java");

    private final File revised = new File("./src/test/resources/files/FileComparatorv2.java");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Comparer comparer = new Comparer();

        comparer.createDiffFile();
    }

    private void createDiffFile() {

        PrintWriter diffFile = null;
        //RandomAccessFile diffFile = null;
        RandomAccessFile oldFile = null;

        try {

            //diffFile = new RandomAccessFile(new File("./diffFile_" + System.currentTimeMillis()), "rw");
            diffFile = new PrintWriter("./diffFile_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "UTF-8");
            oldFile = new RandomAccessFile(original, "r");

            final FileComparator comparator = new FileComparator(original, revised);

            final List<Chunk> changesFromOriginal = comparator.getChangesFromOriginal();

            final int changeNum = changesFromOriginal.size();
            System.out.println("Tamaño de cambios: " + changeNum);

            final List<Integer> changesIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (Chunk change : changesFromOriginal) {

                changesIndex.add(change.getPosition());
            }

            String line = oldFile.readLine();
            int lineIndex = 0;
            while (line != null) {

                if (changesIndex.contains(lineIndex)) {

                    String strikeLine = "From: <strike-through color=yellow>" + line + "</strike-through>"; 
                diffFile.print(strikeLine + " To: <strong>");

                for (Object s : changesFromOriginal.get(changesIndex.indexOf(lineIndex)).getLines()) {
                    diffFile.println(s.toString());
                }
                diffFile.print("</strong>");

                } else {

                    diffFile.println(line);
                }

                line = oldFile.readLine();
                lineIndex++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (diffFile != null) {
                    diffFile.close();
                }

                if (oldFile != null) {
                    oldFile.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output file is

```
package com.onuba.car.javadiff;

import difflib.Chunk;
import difflib.Delta;
import difflib.DiffUtils;
import difflib.Patch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileComparator {

    private final File original;

    private final File revised;

    public FileComparator(File original, File revised) {
        this.original = original;
        this.revised = revised;
    }

    public List<Chunk> getChangesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.CHANGE);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getInsertsFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.INSERT);
    }

    public List<Chunk> getDeletesFromOriginal() throws IOException {
        return getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE.DELETE);
    }

    private List<Chunk> getChunksByType(Delta.TYPE type) throws IOException {
        final List<Chunk> listOfChanges = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        final List<Delta> deltas = getDeltas();
        for (Delta delta : deltas) {
            if (delta.getType() == type) {
                listOfChanges.add(delta.getRevised());
            }
        }
        return listOfChanges;
    }

From: <strike-through color=yellow>    private List<Delta> getDeltas() throws IOException {</strike-through> To: <strong>    private List<Delta> getDeltas(String nuevoParam) throws IOException {
</strong> 
        final List<String> originalFileLines = fileToLines(original);
        final List<String> revisedFileLines = fileToLines(revised);

        final Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(originalFileLines, revisedFileLines);

        return patch.getDeltas();
    }

From: <strike-through color=yellow>    private List<String> fileToLines(File file) throws IOException {</strike-through> To: <strong>    private List<String> fileToLines(File file, String nuevoParam) throws IOException {
</strong>        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        return lines;
    }

From: <strike-through color=yellow>    <style= bold>Hello</style></strike-through> To: <strong>    <style = Italic>Hello</style>

    private void nuevoMetodoCool(File file) {

    }
</strong> 
}
```

Is that usefull for you?

Comment: I will check it out and keep you updated. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Ok, Can you explain me how does your code solve this problem? How are you highlighting differences and interpreting. From what I can understand, you are just getting the differences using java-diff-utils, same which can be achieved with diff_match_patch. What does your code change?

Comment: Yes, I am only getting the files differences. I am not showing anything, this was out of scope of my POC, I thought it could be help for you. Once you have the differences, it should be not hard to show those differences as you want, is not it? Let me give it a try

Comment: That is the real problem to interpret the difference, what you have achieved till now is something which is already present and most importantly it is for plain-text.

Comment: I updated my answer with a class for generate a diff file with the old text strike out, hope helps

Comment: That is not the problem statement. Check the image I have uploaded in main -post where the actual interpretation is with strike-through. Can the code you gave do that?

Comment: yep, the old code appears as strike-through. You can get the file output content, rename as html and open it with a browser in order to see it.

Comment: In this manner : http://pastebin.com/3c65DmvJ    ? Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at output file, strike-through is not a HTML tag, I suppose that is a tag from your framework?

Comment: I just put it as an example. The tag is 'del'.

Comment: oki, you can just custom the file generator class in lines 57 to 63 in order to change the tags as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to to take slightly different approach to solve the problem. 
HTML5 has 'data' attribute where you can add your own information about that particular element. This data tag is completely HTML5 standard.  You can store the HTML element state in it while saving into database. Later when user modifies it, you can compare the current element data of the tag to what you already stored in the 'data' attribute.

Look at this url which explains tells about 'data' attribute. http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Comment: Talked with our JS, HTML developer, says this won't fly as the changes can be a lot which would result in lots of combination to be checked. Even if size of text with respect to HTML elements has changed(which is common), then this won't help.

Comment: I had similar project and this is what exactly I did. Initially it might appear its complex, once you implement it would be very easy. You may want to try POC.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you only want to display the changes as `<old> <new>` with `<old>` strikethrought. You don't want to save them.
To achieve that, you could first build a syntax tree of both the old and the new html code. Then compare the corresponding nodes of those trees. When you find two nodes, which aren't the same, you have found a change. Now you want to show the old version with `strikethrough` and the new version, am I right? So you just can take the code of the old node with `strikethrough` added and next to it the code of the new node.

EDIT:
I have written some code that mostly does this. Although please consider that it was written very very fast and so is not very nice to read and not completely finished. But this question will be closed tomorrow so I thought better that than nothing. Hope it helps :)
[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/HobbyProgrammer/HTMLChangeLocator/)

Comment: Yes, I know this, any implementation you got, what to do if one tree is empty, other is full... such many permutations and combinations...Have some code working? Thank you.

Comment: if a node is missing in one tree and appears in the other it was either deleted or added, depending on the tree. Are there other cases, that can appear?

Comment: Other case includes if the text is changed, or a user adds a unordered list or an ordered list, changes it type, etc. List is one of the major problems.

Comment: I don't see a problem with changing text. How do you want list changes displayed?

Comment: is it possible to add an id to each html tag?

Comment: do you understand it and does it help? Again sorry for the bad coding style